# Using the Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model that basically stores a random hash value for each tag associated with a particular user.

```
class PublicTags(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='hashes')
    hash_value = models.CharField(max_length=103)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tags')
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('tag', 'user')
        verbose_name_plural = 'Public Tag Hashes'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s' % (self.tag, self.user, self.hash_value)
```

I am trying to use the Django Rest Framework to do the following:

- Create a view that will be accessed at api/v1/public_tags.
- I will use AJAX to post data using the Django Rest API.
- On a post, the system does the following:
  It checks to see if there is already a Public Tag row for the tag id (sent via post)
  If not, it creates a random hash_value for that tag and user.

I am confused about how to use the Django Rest Framework to accomplish this task.

I got this far:

```
class PublicTagView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    model = PublicTags
    serializer_class = serializers.PublicTagSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

class RetrieveUpdateAPIView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                            mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                            generics.SingleObjectAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for retrieving or updating a model instance.
    FIXME: the newest version of rest_framework has this class
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need to query an individual record and create a record.
In this case [generic class based views](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views.html#using-generic-class-based-views) are fine enough to start with.

You can then map these views in your urls.py like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/v1/public_tags/$', views.PublicTagsList.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/v1/public_tags/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PublicTagsDetail.as_view()),
)
```

This is valid if you use primary key to fetch individual record.